# How does gluLookAt work?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glut

From my understanding,

```
gluLookAt(
        eye_x, eye_y, eye_z,
        center_x, center_y, center_z,   
        up_x, up_y, up_z
    );
```

is equivalent to:

```
glRotatef(B, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glRotatef(A, wx, wy, wz);
glTranslatef(-eye_x, -eye_y, -eye_z);
```

But when I print out the `ModelView` matrix, the call to `glTranslatef()` doesn't seem to work properly. Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static const int Rx = 0;
static const int Ry = 1;
static const int Rz = 2;

static const int Ux = 4;
static const int Uy = 5;
static const int Uz = 6;

static const int Ax = 8;
static const int Ay = 9;
static const int Az = 10;

static const int Tx = 12;
static const int Ty = 13;
static const int Tz = 14;

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = { 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);
}

void displayModelviewMatrix(float MV[16]) {
    int SPACING = 12;
    cout << left;
    cout << "\tMODELVIEW MATRIX\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << setw(SPACING) << "R" << setw(SPACING) << "U" << setw(SPACING) << "A" << setw(SPACING) << "T" << endl;   
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << setw(SPACING) << MV[Rx] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Ux] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Ax]  << setw(SPACING) << MV[Tx] << endl;
    cout << setw(SPACING) << MV[Ry] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Uy] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Ay]  << setw(SPACING) << MV[Ty] << endl;
    cout << setw(SPACING) << MV[Rz] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Uz] << setw(SPACING) << MV[Az] << setw(SPACING)  << MV[Tz] << endl;
    cout << setw(SPACING) << MV[3] << setw(SPACING) << MV[7] << setw(SPACING) << MV[11] << setw(SPACING) << MV[15] << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    float ratio = static_cast<float>(w)/h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 1.0, 425.0);
}

void draw() {
    float m[16];
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
    gluLookAt(
        300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    );
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidCube(100.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
    displayModelviewMatrix(m);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Demo");
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

No matter what value I use for the `eye` vector:
`300, 0, 0` or
`0, 300, 0` or
`0, 0, 300`
the translation vector is the same, which doesn't make any sense because the order of code is in backward order so `glTranslatef` should run first, then the 2 rotations. Plus, the rotation matrix, is completely independent of the translation column (in the ModelView matrix), then what would cause this weird behavior?
Here is the output with the eye vector is `(0.0f, 300.0f, 0.0f)`

```
        MODELVIEW MATRIX
--------------------------------------------------
R           U           A           T
--------------------------------------------------
0           0           0           0
0           0           0           0
0           1           0           -300
0           0           0           1
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would expect the `T` column to be `(0, -300, 0)`! So could anyone help me explain this?

The implementation of `gluLookAt` from http://www.mesa3d.org

```
void GLAPIENTRY
gluLookAt(GLdouble eyex, GLdouble eyey, GLdouble eyez, GLdouble centerx,
      GLdouble centery, GLdouble centerz, GLdouble upx, GLdouble upy,
      GLdouble upz)
{
    float forward[3], side[3], up[3];
    GLfloat m[4][4];

    forward[0] = centerx - eyex;
    forward[1] = centery - eyey;
    forward[2] = centerz - eyez;

    up[0] = upx;
    up[1] = upy;
    up[2] = upz;

    normalize(forward);

    /* Side = forward x up */
    cross(forward, up, side);
    normalize(side);

    /* Recompute up as: up = side x forward */
    cross(side, forward, up);

    __gluMakeIdentityf(&m[0][0]);
    m[0][0] = side[0];
    m[1][0] = side[1];
    m[2][0] = side[2];

    m[0][1] = up[0];
    m[1][1] = up[1];
    m[2][1] = up[2];

    m[0][2] = -forward[0];
    m[1][2] = -forward[1];
    m[2][2] = -forward[2];

    glMultMatrixf(&m[0][0]);
    glTranslated(-eyex, -eyey, -eyez);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gluLookAt` will rotate and translate the world in a way, that the camera will be located at `{0, 0, 0}` and looks towards the negative z-axis. This is the camera setup used in OpenGL. The camera actually never moves, the world does. Sound confusing? Hell yeah, let me try to explain :)

Lets take this example:

```
eye    :  {300, 0, 0}
lookat :  {  0, 0, 0}
up     :  {  0, 1, 0}

MODELVIEW MATRIX
--------------------------------------------------
R           U           A           T           
--------------------------------------------------
0           0           -1          0           
0           1           0           0           
1           0           0           -300        
0           0           0           1           
--------------------------------------------------
```

First we need to analyze the rotational part of the matrix: `R`, `U` and `A`. As you can see the right vector (`R`) is not in the x-axis anymore `{1, 0, 0}`, it is in the z-axis `{0, 0, 1}`. That means it is rotated by 90 degrees around the y-axis. The same happens to the eye-position. Rotating `{-300, 0, 0}` by 90 degrees around the y-axis lets it end up at `{0, 0, -300}`, voila, there it is.

It is `-300` and not `300` because the world is moved and not the camera, so the world is moved in the opposite direction, still 300 units away from the camera at `{0, 0, 0}`. And again, it is moved towards the negative z-axis, because that is where the OpenGL camera looks to, as mentioned above.

---

Note: there is an an anomaly in your example, the normalized vector from eye-position to look-at-point must not be the same as the up-vector, so:

```
eye    : {0, 300, 0}
lookat : {0,   0, 0}
up     : {0,   1, 0}    

normalize(eye - lookat): {0, 1, 0} -> the same as the up-vector
```

will in fact not work, we must pick another up-vector, for instance `{1, 0, 0}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, though I'm still a little confused although I understand your explanation.