# Move towards view direction opengl?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, c

I'm trying to get the basics of 3d with opengl 2.0(I know, I know, it's deprecated etc, etc. It's just for the sake of prototyping). I'm trying to get a cube on the screen which you can move around. I have rendered the cube, and I can navigate the "world"(black background with the colored cube). However, when I try to rotate the camera, and then move, the camera moves independently of the camera's direction. For example, I rotate 90 degrees to the left, then I press "w" and it looks like I'm strafing to the right.
I use sdl2 to get keyboard input, and when the user presses a key, I increase deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ, rotationX and rotationY accordingly(that's right, no rotation around the z axis).

And the rendering occurs as follows:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Apply transformations
    glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);

    // Draw each face with a different color
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.3, 0.4);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 4, 4);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 8, 4);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 12, 4);
    glColor3f(0.3, 0.8, 0.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 16, 4);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 20, 4);
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: forgot to add, I would like to do this without glu. I don't like linking against a lot of libraries, especially when it's only to get a few functions.

EDIT2: I got forward movement to work using trigonometry like this:

```
case SDLK_w:
    posZ += (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180); // I use rotY * PI/180 to convert rotY to radians
    posX -= (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    break;
case SDLK_s:
    posZ -= (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    posX += (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180);
```

And now the only thing to add is strafing, which I thought would be something like this

```
case SDLK_a:
    posX += (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180) + (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    posZ += (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    break;
case SDLK_d:
    posX -= (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180) + (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    posZ -= (float)sin(rotY * M_PI /180);
    break;
```

But it doesn't work, if you strafe when looking down the x axis, you move backwards in the z axis(wtf?)

Thanks!

EDIT3: Never mind, solved it by doing

```
case SDLK_a:
    posX += (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    posZ += (float)sin(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    break;
case SDLK_d:
    posX -= (float)cos(rotY * M_PI / 180);
    posZ -= (float)sin(rotY * M_PI /180);
    break;
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works. Thanks everyone for helping me!

Comment: Check out [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/how-does-glulookat-work). It explains how the `gluLookAt()` function works.

Comment: I updated the question, I don't want to use glu, I would be linking against an extra library to get a few utilities

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't suggesting using glu. The question above has the implementation of the `gluLookAt()` function in it. I was suggesting you can look at the implementation to get an idea of how to do what you're trying to do, if it would help.

Comment: How about you translate before rotating?

Comment: Unrelated comment: You should stop using deprecated opengl.

Comment: @PandaPajama if I do that, then when I move away from the cube, and then I rotate, the cube turns around it's axis

Comment: A matrix is actually made up of basis vectors that describe the x,y,z axis relative to the transformation of the matrix. In a 3x3 matrix for instance the first row is the x axis vector, the second row is the y axis and the third row is the z axis. (Ignoring row/column major storage orders...).  Using this knowledge, you know the direction to move when the player presses w or s by looking at the last row of the matrix. A and s by the first row of the matrix. Make sure and normalize those vectors before you use them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I would first suggest you use [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/), but you're using C (according to your tag) so probably not. The best math I suggest in that case is continual use of the sine and cosine functions.

My examples will require math.h

You will want to first store your camera's position (if you haven't already)

```
float horizontal = cos(pitch) * GetCameraForwardSpeed();
float x += cos(yaw) * horizontal;
float z -= sin(yaw) * horizontal;
float y += sin(pitch) * GetCameraYSpeed();
//if you wanted strafing, you need this
x -= sin(yaw) * GetCameraStrafeSpeed();
z += cos(yaw) * GetCameraStrafeSpeed();
```

If you are storing degree, you should use a function like this:

```
float ToRadians(float degree)
{
 const double PI_CONST = 3.14159265358979323846;
 return degree * PI_CONST/180;
}
```

and replace yaw and pitch with that.

You will probably want to apply a View and Projection matrix to the position of the other objects, but that is way too much to put as an answer, so I suggest reverse engineering the math in GLM's [perspective and translate](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl) functions and searching through the examples on the use of these functions.

Note: I have stated a few advanced methods of getting the answer

Comment: that's just what I needed. I read a bi about [trigonometry](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html) and got it to work, I'm still struggling with strafing.
And about glm, I'm now using the programable pipeline and implemented all of the projection and modelview transformations on my own, as well as lookAt and a few others. check them out [here](https://github.com/ochi12/PerRepo/tree/master/glm%20replacement%20for%20c)

Answer (score 1):

You typically need to keep track of at least three vectors to be able to easily move a camera around a scene. You need a vector representing the direction you are facing (0,0,-1), one representing upwards (0,1,0) and one vector representing camera position.

After rotating the lookat vector you can then translate your position in the direction of the vector.

Afterwards you can easily construct the ModelView matrix using the three vectors.

See this [tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk) to learn more. It may be slightly out of date in some regards but it is still very useful for beginners